# typescript compiler gives an for code containg generator function

Tags: typescript

I am Learning typescript and while doing so, i came across the concept of generators.

to give them a try I used the following code

```
function* infiniteSequence() {
    var i = 0;
    while(true) {
        yield i++;
    }
}

var iterator = infiniteSequence();
while (true) {
    console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: xxxx, done: false } forever and ever
}
```

But when a try to compile the code using tsc, it gives me this error

```
error TS2339: Property 'next' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

But the generated js code runs fine

I am using ts version 3.1 and node 8.12

my tsconfig file looks like this

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es6"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
  }
}
```

can someone tell me am i doing something wrong, why its showing the error?

**Updated the tsconfig by adding es6 in lib, still the same error**

Comment: Try also adding `"lib": ["es6"]` to your tsconfig file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add "es6" to "lib" option like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
...
```

Comment: [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#Specifications) were initially available in es6, so es7 is not strictly necessary.

Comment: You are right. It's just I personally always add es7 so that even newer features become available. Updated the answer.

Comment: If you want the latest then use `es2018`. If you want features that are still in TC39 proposal stages, you can even use `esnext`